# CSS DIV Margin-top

Tags: css

I have a question about margin in CSS. I have a DIV element, which has an image for background. Inside that DIV I have another DIV. I want this DIV inside to be 200px from the top. But, when I do that, the outside DIV also moves down for 200px. Why is that and how to keep the outside DIV on top?

Comment: It will be much easier for us to help you when you post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: show us your code, please

Comment: Set padding-top on your outside div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set padding-top on your outside div.
For an detailed explanation to your problem see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890354/margin-top-in-a-nested-div).

Comment: Thanks! Well, I added 'overflow: auto' to parent div and than it worked! Thanks for link.