# Margin of inner Div affects outer div

Tags: css, margin

I have three nested DIV elements like this:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="innerA">
        <div id="innerB">
            This<br/>is<br/>a<br/>multiline<br/>testcase.<br/>
            This<br/>is<br/>a<br/>multiline<br/>testcase.<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`#innerA` has a height of `100%` which makes it as big as `#outer`. `#innerB`'s height is left to be `auto` so it gets as high as its contents. Now when i set `#innerB` to have `margin-top: 10px` for example i would expect that `#innerB` will get a margin in relation to `#innerA`. What happens instead is that `#innerA` gets this margin in relation to `#outer`.

How is this possible? It seems like this has nothing to do with `box-sizing` at least its not fixable this way.

Here's the CSS:

```
#outer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}

#innerA {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    background: green;
}

#innerB {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: blue;
}
```

and the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7e2H5/

(Here i would expect that the green DIV fits the yellow one, and that there are 10px of the green one visible above the blue DIV).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like it's a "Margin collapsing" problem. Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7e2H5/)

I've added `padding: 1px 0`;

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing

Just found this: [margin-top in a nested div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890354/margin-top-in-a-nested-div)

Comment: So there's no way to get around this without changing `#innerA` right? What a mess.. is there any situation where this even makes sense?

Comment: Accepted this one, because it gives a lot of information on why css acts this way. The answer of @sureshdeepak solved my problem for now but i think i will have to change this again later.

Answer (score 3):

This is interesting but I wouldn't say that adding padding is a more appropriate answer.

```
#innerA {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7e2H5/7) on JSFiddle.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Mhm this seems to work best (for now) i fear there will be side effects with this one because the container will have different behaviour when other containers are inside. But for now this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace #innerb margin with #innera padding

Answer (score 0):

According to the Mozilla link provided by Chris, adding floats also prevents margins from collapsing:

Add `float: left;` to `#innerA` as shown in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7e2H5/10/

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing