# Div margin not setting properly

Tags: html, css, margin

I am trying to position text using div, but its not working well!

```
.background
{
    background-image:url(bg.png);
    width:600px;
    height:500px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
}

.head1{
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#d45151;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:100px;

}
```

**.background** is the background image of the div whereas **.head1** is a text within .background div.
You can see it in the html part!

```
<div class="background">
<div class="head1">There are 3 CRUCIAL things that you need to remember...</div>
<div class="points">
</div>
</div>
```

The text of class head1 are displayed at positions as they are defined! but it also bring the the background image with it!
It seems quiet confusing so I took a screenshot! please check it out!
Maybe my css is poorly coded. please help me out.

[image]

Comment: you could use `padding-top:100px` for background instead of margin top for head1

Comment: See this post for more details about your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544841/margin-of-inner-div-affects-outer-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto` to parent div.

```
.background {
    background: red;
    width:600px;
    height:500px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.head1 {
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#d45151;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7q5g6yu/2/

Zero margins on `.background` can be removed, zero margin is default value for `div`s.

OR

you can remove the inner div, see this code, it makes the same if you need the inner div just to align the text.

```
<div class="background">
    There are 3 CRUCIAL things that you need to remember...
</div>

<style>
.background {
    background: green;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 100px 0 0 100px;
    color:#d45151; 
    font-style: italic;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7q5g6yu/3/

Comment: Thnks that worked! I didnt had any idea about overflow property! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following style

```
.head1 {
font-size:18px;
font-family:calibri;
font-style:italic;
color:#d45151;
padding: 100px 0 0 100px;
}
```