# vertical gap between elements with margin 0

Tags: html, css

I know this question has [been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975377/css-vertical-gap-between-divs) before, but I don't understand how to elements with `margin:0` have had their margin 'collapse' - they've had their margin 'extended' to me (to a `15px` vertical gap between the two elements - `<header>` & `<nav>`.

Here is the HTML code I am using:

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
      <div class="logo">...</div>
    </header>
    <nav>
      ...
    </nav>
</div>
```

and CSS styles:

```
#container {
    width: 1178px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
header {
    height: 102px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(images/header-bg.jpg);
    margin: 0;
}
nav {
    height: 51px;
    background-image: url(images/navigation-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin: 0;
}
.logo {
    width: 268px;
    height: 69px;
    padding: 22px 0 0 31px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vok0226c/2/) here.

Comment: 15px gap between them? I couldn't get from your current code. You may have 22px gap as you've applied padding to the logo.

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: Are you trying to understand margin-collapsing rules? Then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337043/when-i-try-to-shift-the-image-upwards-using-negative-margin-the-whole-container/35337103#35337103) will help you better.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance folks. @Martin: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vok0226c/2/) here.

Comment: The `ul` has a `margin-top` property which pushes the `nav` down. Remove that to remove the gap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `margin: 0;` for the `<ul>` element.

By default, browsers set `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to `15px`.

```
#menu-primary-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You can see in the image bellow that the `<ul>` element has `margin-top: 15px` even though you didn't set it yourself.

Btw, if you want to keep that `margin-bottom: 15px` then set it on the `<nav>` element not `<ul>` because it's inside `<nav>`. https://jsfiddle.net/cq0LwL8f/1/

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Martin. Are you saying if I only set a `margin-bottom: 15px;` the `margin-top:` is also set to `15px`?

Comment: No, `margin-top` is always set by default by the browser even if you don't style it in any way.

Comment: Right. Didn't know that. Unusual. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the parent elements collapse when the child element is given `float:left` or `float:right`. You need to clear the float in parent element, here in your case parent is `UL` and child is `LI`.

Refer the following css, this may solve:

Assuming this HTML structure:

```
<ul class="clear">
    <li class="floated">...</li>
    <li class="floated">...</li>
    <li class="floated">...</li>
</ul>

.clear:before,
.clear:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Also the `15px` gap you see is because of the `margin-bottom:15px` given.

```
#menu-primary-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

You can adjust the margin (if required) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Nukul Ghosh!