# Css body visible in between section?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 2.3 on my site. I have set the foll css:

```
body,section{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

Yet, for the life of me, I can't understand why I m seeing a white dash of the body in between the sections??
[The Link](http://www.isiddharth.com/beta)

Comment: your link hide please show link properway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<h3>` causes that. Put this:

```
h3{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: the h3 is contained inside the section, yet, the margin is overflowing from it...Y?

Comment: Good [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176520/why-would-margin-not-be-contained-by-parent-element).

Answer (score 0):

Set below style to `<h3>` tag

```
margin-top:0px;
```

Comment: the h3 is contained inside the section, yet, the margin is overflowing from it...Y?

Comment: It's called margin collapsing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102640/css-margin-collapsing

Answer (score 0):

another solution

set below style to `<section>` tag

```
overflow: hidden;
```