# Firebug/jQuery/Safari (perhaps others) report height of element as 100px - should be 110px

Tags: jquery, height, margin

I'm working on a local copy of http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs, and am working with the div with ID 'home' (I've included an edited extract from the relevant bit of the source below).

Firebug and Safari report the height of that div as being 100px (as does jQuery, whether using .height() or .outerHeight(true)). In fact, this can't be, because it contains a paragraph which has content which is 100px high, plus a 10px margin at the bottom - a total of 110px. The consequence of this is that if one actually sets the 'home' div to a height of 100px, it becomes shorter than if one sets height:auto; on it. If one sets the height to 110px, then the height is the same as when using height:auto;.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to a reliable way to calculate the height of the 'home' div within jQuery!

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
   <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade active in" style="">
      <p>
         Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.
      </p>
   </div>
   <div id="profile" class="tab-pane fade" style="">[...]</div>
   <div id="dropdown1" class="tab-pane fade" style="">[...]</div>
   <div id="dropdown2" class="tab-pane fade" style="">[...]</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery documentation, the `.height()` function only measures the actual height of the selected element, without the padding and margin. It also recommends using `.css("height")` if you want the height with padding. See [api.jquery.com/height/](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

You can't reliably measure the height of a div to get the actual height of its children, simply because you can define your div to be smaller than its contents and have it generate a scrollbar. If you want to accurately measure the total height of your div children, you must iterate over each element and get its height. In jQuery you'd use .each(). See [api.jquery.com/each/](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: When you tried the `outerHeight(true)` function, have you made sure the margin is attached to your selected element, rather than a parent element? You also should keep in mind that there can be some asshattery in some browsers where padding and margins will be off by one.

Comment: The margin's attached to the paragraph element within the div whose height I want to know. Assessing the height of the paragraph element yields the correct answer of 110px - but I can't think of a reliable way of assessing the overall height of all child elements within the parent div, and if there's some way of just asking for the height of the parent div, that'd be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of have an answer to this. After fiddling about with a stripped down version of the source and finding that the same problem manifests even when you *only* use the code extract above (ie with no CSS, no JS, and none of the rest of the source), I established that the 'home' div simply doesn't contain the paragraph element's lower margin - ie the parent element just doesn't contain the child element's margin.

This is a manifestation of the problem described at [Why would margin not be contained by parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176520/why-would-margin-not-be-contained-by-parent-element) - and setting overflow:auto; makes it go away, which is acceptable in this case. I don't pretend to understand why, but it works.