# Centered div bottom margin overflowing parent

Tags: css, margin, centering, clearfix

My centered header bottom margin is overflowing the parent container, causing a gap between yellow and orange wrappers:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    .header-wrap{
      background-color:yellow;
    }
    .content-wrap{
      background-color:orange;
    }
    .header{
      margin:0 auto 1em auto;
      background-color: red;
      width:40em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header-wrap">
    <div class="header">header</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="content">content</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use a simple clearfix for parent `.header-wrap{overflow:hidden;}` the problem is fixed, but I don't understand why I need to use a clearfix here, since I'm not using floating elements at all.

From what I know, the clearfix is applied on the parent to clear any floated children inside, which is not the case here.

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: Just to be very clear: I want the header centered and I want that bottom margin on it, it's intended to be there, I just don't understand why that margin overflows the parent, since it's not floated. You can see the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/bJ2e5/2/

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176520/why-would-margin-not-be-contained-by-parent-element

Answer (score 0):

```
.header{
      margin:0 auto 1em auto; //margin 1em at bottom
      background-color: red;
      width:40em;
}
```

change it to

```
.header{
      margin:0 auto;
      background-color: red;
      width:40em;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/64BTy/)

Comment: The whole point of the question is that I want that bottom margin there but I don't understand why it overflows the parent.

Answer (score 0):

**Add float:left or inline-block to your header. Currently in your structure you mentioned the margin-bottom to header div which is inside the header-wrap class. header is the child element. To display yellow background, you must need to wrap the child element.**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R6KHx/)**

**CSS**

```
.header-wrap {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Comment: He is answering not about solution. He is answering why does it happens. And thats a really good question