# Why does the complete image come down, when I give top-margin to the text?

Tags: html, css

Following HTML, displays a picture in the background and text *nhs subscription* written over it. Now when I give `class="nhs_head"` `margin-top` text along with image moves down. Why is it so ?

How can I just give text the margin ?

```
<body>
<div class="image_holder"> 
    <div class="nhs_head"> NHS SUBSCRIPTION </div>       
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    .image_holder {
       position:relative;
       background-image:url(bg2.jpg);
       height:768px;
       width:1366px;
    }

.nhs_head {
    display:block;
    width:60%;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:2px solid white;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-weight:800;
    font-size:30px;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176520/why-would-margin-not-be-contained-by-parent-element

Comment: Use padding-top instead of margin-top. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vwrhk65z/

Comment: @j08691 what happens when you apply the border property ? ! http://jsfiddle.net/vwrhk65z/1/ I had to give it a border too

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/35ncowpf/)**

If you want to apply `margin-top` to text you can position absolute the text in relatively positioned image div.

css

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
}
.image_holder {
    position: relative;
    background-image:url('http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg');
    height:768px;
    width:1366px;
}
.nhs_head {
    width:60%;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:2px solid white;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-weight:800;
    font-size:30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color:white;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```