# white space div when i add text in the middle

Tags: html, css

im getting a white space when im putting text into the div. How to remove that ? i would like  to ask you aswell how to make the text "welkom op dennis website" automatic center in the middle of the div.

here you can see the code :

```css
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.nav {
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
.top {
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #444;
}
.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #444;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  float: right;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #1E90FF;
}
.logo {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p.center {
  padding: 150px 550px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 25px;
   {}
```

```html
<header>
  <title>Dennis Zwart Home Pagina</title>
  <link href="css/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" style="css" />
</header>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="nav">
      <text class="logo">Dennis Zwart</text>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">Games</a>
      <a href="#">Foto's</a>
      <a href="#">Hobby's</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      <p class="center">Welkom op de website van Dennis Zwart</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Isn't the text centered already?

Comment: Yes but im looking for a easyer way ^^

Comment: I have to make my own website for school and i better can learn it right

Comment: Do you need the text vertically centered as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space between your navigation and blue text field is from collapsing margins. You'll need to remove the margins created by your `<p>` element in `.top`, [more on Collapsing Margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176520/why-would-margin-not-be-contained-by-parent-element).

If you need the text vertically centered as well, you can use relative positioning and translate.

#### Other Notes

- `<text>` is not a valid HTML element, use `<p>`, `<span>`, `<div>`, `<a>` etc. instead. I switched it to an `<a>` in my answer.
- I see that you're using percentage **heights**. Those can be tricky. In order for percentage heights to work a height has to be set on the parent element. If that parent element's height is a percentage, then it's parent needs a height set. So on and so forth all the way to the root element `<html>` if percentages are used. In my answer I switch the heights to `px` values.
- A number of block level elements (`<div>`, `<nav>`) had `width: 100%;` applied to them, I removed them as they're not needed. A block level element will always take up 100% width of it's containing element by default.
- To vertically center your navigation items I set the `line-height` of the `<a>` elements equal to the height of the `<nav>` element.
- I removed your `.container` element as it wasn't doing anything useful. You might need it later (likely in a different location) if you decide to add media queries and limit it's width for various viewport sizes.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.nav {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
}
.top {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #444;
}
.nav .logo {
  float: left;
}
.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #444;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #1E90FF;
}
p.center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <title>Dennis Zwart Home Pagina</title>
  <link href="css/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" style="css" />
</header>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
      <a class="logo" href="#">Dennis Zwart</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">Games</a>
      <a href="#">Foto's</a>
      <a href="#">Hobby's</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      <p class="center">Welkom op de website van Dennis Zwart</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for looking in to it. I will copy your notes so i can read them later to.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `p` element has natural margins (defined by browser). Remove it:

```
p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Then remove the `p` horizontal padding and center your text with

```
text-align: center;
```

In order to remove the blank area on the right side of the screen.

```css
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.nav {
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
.top {
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #444;
}
.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #444;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  float: right;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #1E90FF;
}
.logo {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p.center {
  padding: 150px 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <title>Dennis Zwart Home Pagina</title>
  <link href="css/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" style="css" />
</header>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="nav">
      <text class="logo">Dennis Zwart</text>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">Games</a>
      <a href="#">Foto's</a>
      <a href="#">Hobby's</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      <p class="center">Welkom op de website van Dennis Zwart</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks its work :D, How to fix the white area on the left of the site ?

Comment: @dennis Don't center your text with `padding`, I edit my answer to fix the white area. Read it...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/85g2jhl6hn6sm52/Screenshot%202016-10-14%2023.18.40.png?dl=0

Comment: the page is going much smaller somehow ^^

Comment: thanks for looking in to it. The other guy fixed evrything with a explain ^^