# CSS moving a div vertically down

Tags: html, css

Im trying to move a div inside another div down a bit, but when I use

```
margin-top: 10px;
```

It makes a white gap at the top. Heres the html:

```
<div id="topb">
    <div id="selection">

    </div>
</div>
```

And heres the CSS:

```
#topb {
    background: url(images/tomato-background.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 101%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#selection {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    width: 60%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

And heres a screenshot of the website:
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a margin top of 40px in the #selection. Where is your margin top of 10px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can modify the parent element by adding `padding-top:10px;` instead of modifying the child.

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can use `position: absolute`. Here is the code:

```css
#topb {
    background: url(images/tomato-background.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 101%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#selection {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    width: 60%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;  /*This is where it is changed as well as the line above*/
}
```

Hope it helps! I think padding would still leave a background, so this is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin-top style in #selection, and apply padding-top to #topb

Comment: Doesnt do anything. Literally. looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/eOfPh

Comment: Indeed. Wrong :)  I've edited it. Anyway, you've got your problem solved and that is great!

Answer (score 0):

This is a "collapsed margin" problem.
It has been answered in this question :
[Why would margin not be contained by parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176520/why-would-margin-not-be-contained-by-parent-element)

You would have to change the parent div to either (1) add a border, (2) position absolute, (3) display as inline-block, (4) overflow auto.

Refer to the posted link for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7y3y9nq7/2/) Hope it may help.

```
position:absolute;
position:relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you have a block element (display: block) inside another block element, the margins will collapse. It will only be considered the largest margin.

So, in your example it will only consider one of the margins (40px).
[See reference about collapsing margins](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/).

There are a few workarounds. Choose any:

1. using `padding` instead of `margin`for the component inside.
2. Change `display` type. e.g. `display: inline-block`.
3. Use `absolute` positioning.